# Will loading /data/data/packagename/files/liba.so through the System.load() api violate the "Device and Network Abuse" agreement

Tags: google-play

Can I store the .so file in the APP assets directory, copy assets/so to the getFilesDir directory when running the APP, and then load the SO file through the system.load() api? Will it violate the "Device and Network Abuse" agreement, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888379?hl=en

```
val cpuAbi = "armeabi-v7a"
        val assetManager = assets
        val inputStream = assetManager.open("jni/$cpuAbi/liba.so")
        val tempFile = File.createTempFile("liba", ".so", filesDir)
        tempFile.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
        }
        System.load(tempFile.absolutePath)
```

Will it violate the "Device and Network Abuse" agreement, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888379?hl=en